# strict mode filter in angularjs is not working

Tags: angularjs

[image]

The below line of code is not working. It gives all the list. But why its not giving desired result?

```
$scope.search = "Ernst Handel";
$scope.disableFilter = false;
$scope.records = [{
        "Name": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
        "Country": "Germany"
    }, {
        "Name": "Berglunds snabbköp",
        "Country": "Sweden"
    }, {
        "Name": "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
        "Country": "Mexico"
    }, {
        "Name": "Ernst Handel",
        "Country": "Austria"
    }, {
        "Name": "Ernst Handelll",
        "Country": "Austriaaa"
    }]

<tr ng-repeat="x in records | filter:(!disableFilter || '') && {Name:search}.true ">
    <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{x.Country}}</td>
</tr>`
```

Its giving all the item in tabular format as below.

```
Alfreds Futterkiste Germany
Berglunds snabbköp  Sweden
Centro comercial Moctezuma  Mexico
```

But my desired result should be only

```
Ernst Handel    Austria
```

Thanks once again. But I want to use filter on some condition and that to for strict match

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in records | filter:(!disableFilter || '') && {Name:search}.true ">
```

Depending upon `disableFilter`, my filter should be applied.

Comment: Ah. And do you have any question?

Comment: What is the question exactly??

Comment: it's not clear what the desired result would be here.

Comment: see   $scope.disableFilter = false; $scope.search = "Ernst Handel";    it should give only strict match resulr. that is "Ernst Handel".

Comment: You need to post all of your code.

Comment: please find mu updated question @VSO

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working filter you want: [PLUNK](https://plnkr.co/edit/MdGMe0RKJbZ8yOjxEwmI?p=preview)

```
<table class ="table">
  <tr style="font-weight:bold; background-color:grey;">
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Country</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in records | filter:search">
        <td>{{x.name}}</td>
        <td>{{x.country}}</td>
  </tr>`
</table>

$scope.search = "Alfreds Futterkiste";

$scope.records = [
   {
       name: "Alfreds Futterkiste",
       country: "Germany"
   }, {
       name: "Berglunds snabbköp",
       country: "Sweden"
   }
]
```

If you are concerned about lower and upper case, let us know.

Comment: noo.. this not what i want... i want  strict filter based on my condition

Comment: @PinakiPrasadMohapatra: Do you want only the results that strictly match $scope.search to show? If so, see my answer. If not, I will come back and think about it later.

Comment: @PinakiPrasadMohapatra P.S. You CAN write a filter to do what I did with ng-if, but to the best of my knowledge, it would HAVE to be a custom filter.

Comment: thank you for ur support. But in want in ng-repeat filter

Comment: @PinakiPrasadMohapatra: I updated the answer again. If that's not what you need, I recommend updating your question. This is fairly simple stuff, so you should get help soon from someone else.

Comment: Thanks once again. But i want to use filter on some condition and that to for strict match                                   <tr ng-repeat="x in records | filter:(!disableFilter || '') && {Name:search}.true ">                                             Depending Upon disableFilter , my Fillter shoud be applied

Comment: @PinakiPrasadMohapatra what is `{Name:search}.true`supposed to mean. This is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: @JBNizet {Name:search}.true for strict search in angularjs Filter

Comment: What do you mean by "strict"?